# Aligning single and double digit number with space in csv

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel-file that i need to save to a .csv or .txt to create a specific formatted file to a software I'm using. Two of the columns in the .csv or .txt contains data with single and double digit numbers. When saving excel-file to .csv or .txt these columns will be separated with the according separating value (semicolon, tab, aso.)

What I'm looking for is how to add a space in front of the single digit number so that it aligns to the right properly with the double digit number. I have tried to figure this out in the custom number formatting but I always end up with spaces both in front of the double digit and single digit.

To try and illustrate (left side is standard csv, right side is what I'm looking for):

```
;14;3;   --> ;14; 3;

;12;22;  --> ;12;22; 
;13;5;   --> ;13; 5;
```

Comment: You can try saving as **Formatted Text (Space delimited)**, as [this Superuser Stack Exchange article](http://superuser.com/questions/100433/export-an-excel-spreadsheet-to-fixed-width-text-file) describes in detail.  If you insist on your exact format, you might have to do some heavy lifting in your actual Excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The displayed format (cell number formatting) is exported as the CSV element value. Use a number format of `[>9]0;_(0` to add a prefacing space to single digit values.

```
col1,col2,col3
AA, 2,2.00
BB, 3,3.00
CC, 4,4.00
DD, 5,5.00
EE, 6,6.00
FF, 7,7.00
GG, 8,8.00
HH, 9,9.00
II,10,10.00
JJ,11,11.00
KK,12,12.00
LL,13,13.00
MM,14,14.00
```

The middle field receive the custom number format.